# What kind of join is used in a Vertica UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, vertica

Vertica has an interesting update syntax when updating a table based on a join value. Instead of using a join to find the update rows, it mandates a syntax like this:

```
UPDATE a
SET col = b.val
where a.id = b.id
```

(Note that this syntax is indeed mandated in this case, because Vertica prohibits us from using a where clause that includes a "self-join", that is a join referencing the table being updated, in this case `a`.)

This syntax is nice, but it's less explicit about the join being used than other SQL dialects. For example, what happens in this case?

```
UPDATE a
SET col = CASE 0 if b.id IS NULL ELSE b.val END
where a.id = b.id
```

What happens when `a.id` has no match in `b.id`? Does `a.col` not get updated, as though the condition `a.id = b.id` represented an inner join of `a` and `b`? Or does it get updated to zero, as if the condition were a left outer join?

Comment: what is `b` in the query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Vertica uses the Postgres standard for this syntax:

```
UPDATE a
    SET col = b.val
    FROM b
    whERE a.id = b.id;
```

This is an `INNER JOIN`.  I agree that it would be nice if Postgres and the derived databases supported explicit `JOIN`s to the update table (as some other databases do).  But the answer to your question is that this is an `INNER JOIN`.

I should note that if you want a `LEFT JOIN`, you have two options.  One is a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE a
    SET col = (SELECT b.val FROM b whERE a.id = b.id);
```

The other is an additional level of `JOIN` (assuming that `id` is unique in `a`):

```
UPDATE a
    SET col = b.val
    FROM a a2 LEFT JOIN
         b
         ON a2.id = b.id
    WHERE a.id = a2.id;
```

Comment: Do either of these solutions run afoul of the ["no self-joins" rule](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/UPDATE.htm)? I would guess that the first solution is OK but the second is not?

Comment: I know I could just try this and see what Vertica allows, but I have had bad experiences with Vertica failing silently and producing garbage results on this kind of self-join update query.

Comment: @Paul . . . Well, the last query clearly violates this rule.  I don't know if Vertica permits correlated subqueries in `UPDATE`s.  This answer is based on the syntax similarity to Postgres, and all three queries should work in Postgres.

Comment: Would it be more canonical to rely on the default value, so that no update is even needed when there isn't a match? I'm migrating code from MS Access SQL and it's possible the idioms in there don't transfer well.

Comment: @Paul . . . It would probably be simpler if you could use a default value.